# Guidance / Fortune Synergy

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

How does the +1 bonus from the Guidance cantrip work with the extra roll from the Fortune witch hex?

**GUIDANCE**
School divination; Level cleric 0, druid 0
Casting Time 1 standard action
Components V, S
Range touch
Target creature touched
Duration 1 minute or until discharged
Saving Throw Will negates (harmless); Spell Resistance yes

This spell imbues the subject with a touch of divine guidance. The creature gets a +1 competence bonus on a single attack roll, saving throw, or skill check. It must choose to use the bonus before making the roll to which it applies.

**Fortune (Su)**: The witch can grant a creature within 30 feet a bit of good luck for 1 round. The target can call upon this good luck once per round, allowing him to reroll any ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check, taking the better result. He must decide to use this ability before the first roll is made. At 8th level and 16th level, the duration of this hex is extended by 1 round. Once a creature has benefited from the fortune hex, it cannot benefit from it again for 24 hours.

**Example**: Witch casts guidance on friend before he makes a big jump to give him +1 acrobatics, lasts for one minute. Then, witch uses fortune hex right before he jumps. Does the friend add +1 to the whatever the better result of the double roll?

Maybe also before a diplomacy check, or running through a trap, or a long distance sniper shot?

Comment: I added an example to the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless they state otherwise, **rerolls always use all the same bonuses and penalties that applied to the original roll, so yes**, you've got it right.  A reroll is exactly that:  you make the same roll again.

Comment: Since you're asking questions about the Fortune hex, I also wanted to point the Cackle hex in case you haven't noticed it yet.  Use your standard action first to set up Fortune, then Cackle to add a round to it's duration.  Rinse and repeat until the entire party has Fortune.  Now start with your favorite debuff on the enemy, still Cackling with your move actions (Misfortune is nice).  Allies roll twice and take the higher, enemies roll twice (for EVERY roll, not just once per round) and take the lower.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. And that's why witches are so badass!